# Proof that special orthogonal group SO(3) is not abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I have to show that $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ is **not** an abelian group.

I tried proving these points:

1. $A^{-1}$ exists $\forall A \in \operatorname{SO}(3),$
2. if $A,B \in \operatorname{SO}(3)$, then $AB\in \operatorname{SO}(3),$
3. $\forall A,B \in \operatorname{SO}(3),\ AB=BA.$

and managed to prove them all, therefore $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ should be an abelian group according to my proof. But I know this is wrong and it shouldn't be an abelian group...

I'd greatly appreciate it if you could help me out here to spot where I am wrong. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is a group but it is not Abelian! Product of matrices is not commutative in general. Check that rotations of let's say 90º w.r.t. X and Y axes do not commute with each other!

Specific counterexample: 

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$A$ and $B$ corresponds to the aforementioned rotations in $SO(3)$.

Comment: $SO(3)$ has some obvious non-abelian subgroups, for example finite dihedral groups, see the duplicate. Hence $SO(3)$ cannot be abelian itself.