# Proving The group SO(N) is non-abelian

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory

I can’t seem to find the answer to this question anywhere. i know that SO(N) is non-abelian when N = 3 but is this true for any other N’s? If so, is there a way to prove, with a generalized proof, that SO(N) is non-abelian for a certain N?

Thank you

Comment: $SO(3)$ is a subgroup of $SO(N)$ for all $N \geq 3$ so if $SO(3)$ is non-Abelian so is $SO(N)$.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433461/proof-that-special-orthogonal-group-so3-is-not-abelian-group?noredirect=1&lq=1).